# Searching for info in large arrays

Tags: powershell, large-data

I've got a script which indexes information from our equipment. To store and analyze the information I've created a class:

```
Add-Type @'
public class CPObject
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string displayname;
    public string classname;
    public string ip;
    public string netmask;
    public string ManagementServer;
}
'@
```

Then when I run the script I've been planning to go through the object class to translate name to IP with the following function:

```
Function NameToIP {

    Param([int]$id=0, [string]$name="")

    $CPObject = $CPNetworkObjects | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $id -and $_.name -eq $name }

    If($CPObject.count -eq 1){
        $CPObject.ip
    } else {
        ""
    }
}
```

It works, but it's terribly slow as the $CPNetworkObjects contains over 12 000 elements of the type CPObject.

I want to speed this up. Is there any way to index an array to make the search more efficient or is the only solution to try to lessen the number of objects used?

Kind regards,
Patrik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any give combination of id plus name is unique, you can speed up a name-to-ip resolution by building a lookup table:

```
$NameToIP = @{}

Foreach ($Object in $Array) { $NameToIP["$($Object.id)_$($Object.Name)"] = $Object.ip }

Function NameToIP {

    Param([int]$id=0, [string]$name="")

    $NameToIP["$id_$name"]

 }
```

Comment: I read that hash tables were faster, but I did not think of this. Smart suggestion. I will try it and get back to you!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much much faster now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use a pscustomobject instead of a class ?
searching an array of 15000 simple objects doesnt seem too long :

```
PS>(1..15000) |%{                                                         
>>> $res+=new-object pscustomobject -property @{"id"=$_;name=(get-random)}
>>> }                                                                     

PS> measure-command -expression {$res |?{$_.id -eq 14999 -and $_.name -eq 513658722}}
```

takes 802ms

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to index an array to make the search more efficient

First of all, I don't know a thing about powershell so I won't be able to give you code samples.

### If you can change your data structure

If either the id or name is unique, you should try to remove this unique field from your CPObject and use it as the key for your hash map, and have your CPObject as the value returned by the hash table.

### If you cannot change your data structure

You should try to sort your array using the name and/or the id
You can go from O(n) time complexity O(log(n)) when looking for a name to

Hope this helped,